# Using text-align center in colgroup

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table in my page. I use colgroups to format all cells in this column the same way. It works well for background color and all. but I cannot seem to figure out why text-align center does not work. It does not align the text centered.

Example:

```
<table id="myTable" cellspacing="5">
    <colgroup id="names"></colgroup>
    <colgroup id="col20" class="datacol"></colgroup>
    <colgroup id="col19" class="datacol"></colgroup>
    <colgroup id="col18" class="datacol"></colgroup>

    <thead>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>20</th>
        <th>19</th>
        <th>18</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
#names {
    width: 200px;
}

#myTable .datacol {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Only [a limited set of CSS properties applies to columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#columns), and `text-align` isn't one of them.

See ["The mystery of why only four properties apply to table columns"](http://ln.hixie.ch/?start=1070385285&count=1) for a description of why this is the case.

In your simple example, the easiest way to fix it would be to add these rules:

```css
#myTable tbody td { text-align: center }
#myTable tbody td:first-child { text-align: left }
```

That would center all table cells, except the first column. This doesn't work in IE6, but in IE6 the `text-align` *does* actually (wrongly) work on the column. I don't know if IE6 supports all properties, or just a larger subset.

Oh, and your HTML is invalid. `<thead>` misses a `<tr>`.

Comment: so you are saying it just is not possible and he only way to achieve this would be to do it on the TD element itself then

Comment: Yep. I've added a fix for your example, though that's not going to work if the table gets any more complicated. DisgruntledGoat provides a few more solutions.

Comment: Both of those suggestions regarding the missing tr inside thead are invalid, too.  th doesn't belong in tbody and td doesn't belong in thead.  Just add a tr to contain the th's inside thead.

Comment: @graywh, I agree it's best to keep the `th` in the `thead`, so I've removed my suggestions. It's perfectly valid, and may be appropriate, to have a `th` in the `tbody` or a `td` in the `thead`, though. E.g. a header column can't go in the `thead`, and descriptions of headers could go in `td`s in the `thead`. But neither is probably the case here.

Comment: @wtjones, that's because IE quirks mode (in any version of IE) is essentially the same as IE5.5 (so don't use it!). If you have no choice, you can make it work in quirks mode the same way as in IE6 (i.e. by setting `text-align` on the `col`/`colgroup` anyway).

Comment: The <col> elements supports only 3 style rules : border, background, width and visibility. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1238151/1158647

Answer (score 25):

See a similar question: [Why is styling table columns not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119106/why-is-styling-table-columns-not-allowed)

You are only allowed to set **border**, **background**, **width** and **visibility** properties, due to the fact that cells aren't direct descendents of columns, only of rows.

There are a few solutions. The simplest is to add a class to each cell in the column. Unfortunately that means more HTML, but it shouldn't bee a problem if you're generating tables from a database, etc.

Another solution for modern browsers (i.e., not [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6)) is to use some pseudo classes. `tr > td:first-child` will select the first cell in a row. Opera, Safari, Chrome and Firefox 3.5 also support the `:nth-child(n)` selector so you can target specific columns.

You could also use `td+td` to select from the second column onwards (it actually means "select all `td` elements that have one `td` element to its left). `td+td+td` selects from the third column - you can continue in this fashion, overriding properties. Honestly though, it's not great code.

Answer (score 6):

With the following CSS, you can just append one or more classes to the the table element in order to align its columns accordingly.

CSS

```css
.col1-right td:nth-child(1) {text-align: right}
.col2-right td:nth-child(2) {text-align: right}
.col3-right td:nth-child(3) {text-align: right}
```

HTML

```
<table class="col2-right col3-right">
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1 will be left</td>
    <td>Column 2 will be right</td>
    <td>Column 2 will be right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HHZsw/

Comment: true, though small remark: those selectors are `CSS3` selectors, and usable in IE9 and higher. If you need support for lower versions of IE, you cannot use this method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the limitations mentioned in other answers, as of February 2018, *visibility:collapse* still does not work on colgroups in Chrome and Chromium based browsers, due to a bug. See *[CSS col visibility:collapse does not work on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395438/css-col-visibilitycollapse-does-not-work-on-chrome)*.

So I believe the currently usable properties are just border, background, and width (unless you employ some sort of [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) for Chrome and other Chromium-based browsers). The bug can be tracked at *[Issue 174167: visibility:collapse does not work correctly for table columns or rows](https://crbug.com/174167)*.