# Specifying the width and text alignment of a column

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to specify the width of a table column in percentages using css?
Also is it possible to specify the text alignment of a specific column?

For example I have a table that has 3 columns.
I would like to say

```
col1.width = 20%
col2.width = 40%
col3.width = 40%

col1.text-align = left;
col2.text-align = right;
col3.text-align = center;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question: create classes that you assign to each `col`umn. Rather simple.

The aligning of text is a bit more difficult, as you can only assign a [few properties to table columns](http://ln.hixie.ch/?count=1&start=1070385285) as a whole. In this case, one solution would be to use the `nth-child` pseudo-class, but that's a CSS 3 specific feature that's not working in any of the current versions of Internet Explorer. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238115/using-text-align-center-in-colgroup/1238248#1238248) proposes, you can also use the `+` combinator to style adjacent columns. That's a CSS 2.1 feature [supported by IE >= 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#combinators).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<title>Column styling</title>
<style>
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 1000px;
}

.firstColumn {
    width: 20%;
    background: #ccc;
}

.otherColumns {
    width: 40%;
    background: #eee;
}

td       { text-align: left }
td+td    { text-align: right }
td+td+td { text-align: center }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <col class="firstColumn">
    <col class="otherColumns">
    <col class="otherColumns">
    <tr>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but your `<td>` widths are relative to the parent container at this point.

Comment: How exactly would I do this? Do I have to give each td element a class? Or wrap the tds in a div and specify the width for the div? Which is the correct way to do it?