# Why text-align doesn't work in colgroup?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

What is wrong with this XHTML 1.1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html><body><table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 10em; text-align: right;" />
    <col style="width: 10em;" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></body></html>
```

The problem is that `test1` is not aligned to right, as it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238115/using-text-align-center-in-colgroup/1238151#1238151) already. Basically `text-align` doesn't apply to columns.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, this would help you: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#columns