# w3c's colgroup example invalid?

Tags: w3c, html4, colgroup

I know that you can't use text-align in CSS on colgroup, however, in the HTML 4.01 spec an [example table is given](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#sample) using align="center". However, I can't seem to get their exact code to work (checked in moz and webkit)!? Should I care to request a correction? Looks like I just need to move on to [CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1238248)!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely move on. `align` on `colgroup` was one of those HTML 4 spec features that never got widely implemented. I note that HTML5 does not even mention it. It's neither valid, nor marked as obsolete, which suggests that, to browser manufacturers, it never really existed at all.

Comment: Yeah, i felt like I entered a black whole for a moment then. Ended up solving it using CSS3 selectors and leaving it as a progressive enhancement.