# CSS col visibility:collapse does not work on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table, colgroup

I'm trying to hide some col's in html code.  Using MDN colgroup and col are added, and I'm playing with the style of the cols.

The `<td>` with content text 'visible' is visible in all browsers (good), the  with content text 'hidden' is visible in chrome (bad) and hidden in Firefox and Edge.  (good).

Shortest code I could re-create problem is here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>css example</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            col.visible {}
            col.hidden { visibility:collapse; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border='1'>
            <colgroup>
                <col class='visible'>
                <col class='hidden'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>visible</td>
                        <td>hidden</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </colgroup>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71752219/collapsed-table-columns-leave-visible-artifacts-behind)

Comment: Current bug tracking ticket on [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1266352)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, chrome doesn't properly support visibility:collapse for table rows and columns -- follow the [bug](https://crbug.com/174167) for updates. We are planning on tackling it in the next few months but it probably won't show up in stable until the end of 2017. Sorry about the bad news.

Comment: Still nothing ?

Comment: visibility:collapse for rows should work now but not columns yet, or probably anytime soon.

Comment: Update: Column collapsing finally works in Chrome 91.

Comment: @dgrogan But it's [still buggy in current Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71752219/collapsed-table-columns-leave-visible-artifacts-behind) Version 100.0.4896.127 (64-Bit)

Answer (score 0):

The `visibility: collapse` should not be assigned to `col`, but `td`. This will work fine:

```css
td.hidden { visibility:collapse; }
```

```html
    <body>
        <table border='1'>
            <colgroup>
                <col>
                <col>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>visible</td>
                        <td class='hidden'>hidden</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </colgroup>
        </table>
    </body>
```

If you want to hide all `td`s from a specific `col`, use `td:nth-of-type(n)` selector (replacing `n` with the index number of column).

Comment: Wrong.  By W3, see the next : https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/folding.en.html#view05

Comment: All right, it's more of a workaround because that actually works fine in Chrome. Sorry for misinformation.

Comment: this is exactly what I did once dgrogan had wrote his answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of Chrome 92, the symptoms are the same: <col style=visibility:collapse> renders the column invisible, but its width is not zero, so the table occupies the same width as if un-collapsed.

The idea of using <colgroup> + <col> is to *avoid adding markup to every <td>* in the column.

Comment: Could you give an example test case? http://wpt.live/css/css-tables/visibility-collapse-col-005.html has <col span="2" style="background:#F00; visibility: collapse"/> and gives the column zero width.

Comment: As of Chrome 94, the symptom remains.  I cannot paste an image here to illustrate.  But the problem is that
    <col style="visibility:collapse">
gives the column zero width, but the un-collapsed width is subtracted from the available width of the container.  The result is that collapsing several columns does not allow the un-collapsed columns to expand, causing them to line-break.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not following the explanation. I don't think we have any reported issues about this but I believe you that there is a probable bug here. Could you make a jsfiddle or codepen or something that demonstrates? You can either link that here and I'll file a chrome issue or you can create the issue yourself if you'd like (https://crbug.com/new -- you can skip/delete "Other browsers tested" section)

Comment: Here is a concise test case: https://jsfiddle.net/ojkr8y62/

Comment: Oh. That is intentional. Ctrl-f for 'however' at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility#values for a brief explanation. I put an explanation and demo in https://jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/ft90rqbj/4/.

As step 4 in the fiddle says, I don't see an easy way to do what you want. I filed https://crbug.com/1257766. If anyone wants the line-breaking behavior described by @dave, please star the bug AND add a brief explanation of your use case.