# Aligning text in table column group in HTML5

Tags: css, html, text-align, col, colgroup

I am trying to align (center) content in group of a columns in my table. I've learned about `colgroup` and `col` elements (never used them before). I've learned that those elements had `align` attribute, but now, in HTML, it's gone.

On w3school service I've seen this note:

> Compatibility Notes
>
> The align attribute of  is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS
>   instead.
>
> CSS syntax: `<td style="text-align:right">`

Does it mean, than aligning feature of column/column group was removed and now I must put style/class element on every cell in that column? What `col` and `colgroup` elements can be used for then? I've seen that setting `background-color` still works. Anything else?

P.S.
It's a poor experience, to learn about a feature and right away learn, that actually you can't use it already :/

---

Edit:
As asked by @JLe, I've added this example code:

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2" style="background-color:red; text-align: center;">
    <col style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ISBN</td>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Price - longer</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3476896</td>
      <td>My first HTML - long title</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">$53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5869207</td>
      <td>My first CSS</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">$49</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I was able to center content of the yellow cells through cell style, but I am asking whether there is a way to put that aligning code into `colgroup`, as I did with red columns, but it certainly does not work.

Comment: Can you post some of your code so that we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'll add one in a moment, but does it actually require an example code? It's not something complicated - I want to center-align content of cells in columns through `col` or `colgroup` element, as it used to work (with attribute) earlier (before HTML5).

Comment: It's just easier to give a good practice example if you can see what you're actually trying to do in this case. But I would advise you to just add a class to cells you want to align, like `<td class="cell-center">` and then specify that in your CSS. Or, give each column a class that represents that column, and you can control the alignment for each context in your CSS.

Comment: This question is already answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238115/using-text-align-center-in-colgroup

Comment: It seems like you try to align center everything in the table. You can just add <style>td{text-align:center;}</style> to solve this.

Comment: @LSKhan thanks, I did not see that one. So indeed it is impossible already. I've read the article mentioned in your linked anwer, but I still don't understand why this feature was removed.

@chrisbergr it's just an example. I want to align only single `colgroup`. I've added the per-cell-style only as an example of how I don't want to do it, but it seems that I will have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I should've been more clear on this in the comments, but no, you can't text-align it using col. It doesn't work by spec.

What you could do instead, is use CSS to align the different children of each `tr` element, as that is somewhat the same thing.

```html
<style>
    tr td:nth-child(-n+2) {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2" style="background-color:red; text-align: center;">
    <col style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ISBN</td>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Price - longer</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3476896</td>
      <td>My first HTML - long title</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">$53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5869207</td>
      <td>My first CSS</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">$49</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To create more advanced selectors you can join them, making an AND statement (or union for that matter). So to select element 2-5 in a sequence, create one selector that selects the first five, and one that selects 2, 3, ... until the end:

```css
tr td:nth-child(-n+5):nth-child(n+2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah right, the child selectors ... eh, I haven't used CSS for ages. Will have to look at this. Is there e.g. an "from 2nd to 5th child" selector?

Comment: @SoulReaver Yes there is. I have edited my post and added an example that does that.