# Better way to right align text in an HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with a large number of rows, and I need to right align one column.

I know the following ways,

```
<tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td align='right'>10.00</td><tr>
```

and

```
<tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td class='right-align-class'>10.00</td><tr>
```

In both the methods, I have to repeat the align or class parameter on every `<tr>` tag. (If there are 1000 rows, I have to put *align='right'* or *class='right-align-class'* 1000 times.)

Is there an efficient way to do this? *Is there a direct way to say, align the third column in all rows to the right?

Comment: I suggest whatever is generating the HTML should be adding the right alignment to the output so that you don't have to type it 1000 times. If you have a thousand rows in a table it should be generated programmatically to begin with. This means you only have to change the alignment in the template or the code that generates the html, and you only do this once. This isn't exactly an answer to your question. But I know I often find I am doing something not quite like others that leads me to ask questions I wouldn't even have if one layer deeper I was doing things differently. Look one layer deepr

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Updated (after 10+ years!):** Yes! It's possible to do this more efficiently now, with widespread practical browser support, using the `nth-child` selector.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>foo 1</td>
<td>bar 1</td>
<td>baz 1</td>
<td>bap 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo 2</td>
<td>bar 2</td>
<td>baz 2</td>
<td>bap 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table td { width: 20em; border: 1px solid black; }
table td:nth-child(3) { text-align: end; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mv83qszL/

Previously, it was not possible to do this, because browser support used to be inconsistent and hit-or-miss, especially with regard to newer CSS features. This made it impossible to use more elegant, efficient solutions -- and required lots of repetitive markup and class definitions in order to get consistent results across the audience's browser space.

See the edit history for the previous version of this answer.

Comment: Why is this getting upvoted? He just repeated the same method the OP already knew about.

Comment: But it's not more efficient.  Having to add a class to each `td` is the most compatible way, but not the most efficient.  The most efficient way would be to use the `nth-child(3)` selector.

Comment: There's also the sibling selector solution, which only requires you add a class to the table and is supported by all browsers other than IE6.  That is also a more efficient solution (especially if the code is maintained by hand).

Comment: Where are all these 10% of the population who uses IE6? I don't think I ever met one of them.

Comment: "IE6 is still 10% of the browsing population -- and you still have to contend with that"
No.... I don't. People on IE6 deserve to be miserable.

Comment: @MattHowell: This awesome answer looks time-sensitive and outdated (your links disprove your text, the 40% figure which is a key point in your argument), could you refresh it ?

Comment: This is still relevant, in fact it is no more or less efficient than decrying .css altogether and just using "align". OP does not disambiguate what is meant by efficient. I find it hard to imagine all these rows are not written by a preprocessor (php say).  Align should be supported in perpetuity across the board for backwards compatibility. After a while the .css bloat can mean it is more efficient to serve an image !

Answer (score 18):

You could use the `nth-child` pseudo-selector.  For example:

```css
table.align-right-3rd-column td:nth-child(3)
{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Then in your table do:

```
<table class="align-right-3rd-column">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, this only works in Firefox 3.5.  However, if your table only has three columns, you could use the sibling selector, which has much better browser support.  Here's what the style sheet would look like:

```css
table.align-right-3rd-column td + td + td
{
  text-align: right;
}
```

This will match any column preceded by two other columns.

Comment: Unfortunately not a very compatible solution.

Comment: @cdmckay: actually it should work in the latest versions of Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari. No IE support though.

Comment: Would any of the downvoters care to say what is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 9):

If it's always the third column, you can use this (assuming table class of "products"). It's kind of hacky though, and not robust if you add a new column.

```css
table.products td+td+td {
  text-align: right;
}
table.products td,
table.products td+td+td+td {
  text-align: left;
}
```

But honestly, the best idea is to use a class on each cell. You can use the `col` element to set the width, border, background or visibility of a column, but not any other properties. [Reasons are discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119106/why-is-styling-table-columns-not-allowed).

Comment: also doesn't work if you use variable colspan (or any rowspan) on some of the preceding columns

Answer (score 6):

Looking through your *exact* question to your **implied** problem:

Step 1:  Use the class as you described (or, if you must, use inline styles).

Step 2:  Turn on GZIP compression.

It works wonders ;)

This way, GZIP removes the redundancy for you (over the wire, anyway) and your source remains standards compliant.

Comment: +1 for turning on GZIP. Seriously, this answer does not warrant 3 downvotes. Other less compatible answer should be voted down instead.

Comment: I wasn't advocating inline styles as the best way by any means.  It was just one possibility on how to solve the problem.

Comment: +1, downvoters explain? This is not any different than the top answer at the moment, and on top of that it is the only sensible solution.

Comment: Whether it's "sensible" depends on the goal: the original question sounded like it was about semantic repetition, not bandwidth, so GZIP sounds irrelevant to me.  The FAQ says downvotes on SO are for "off topic or incorrect" answers.  IMHO, simply being "less compatible" should not be grounds for downvoting, but GZIP is borderline offtopic.  (FWIW, I did not downvote anything on this page.)  (Goodbye, karma!  I barely knew ye.)

Comment: @John: Maybe you should *bold* the "or" word on your #1.
@Ken: GZIPing will make it more efficient than *not* GZIPing (which is the one of the question asked).

Answer (score 2):

A number of years ago (in the IE only days) I was using the `<col align="right">` tag, but I just tested it and and it seems to be an IE only feature:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <col align="left" />
        <col align="left" />
        <col align="right" />
        <tr>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3476896</td>
            <td>My first HTML</td>
            <td>$53</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The snippet is taken from [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_col.asp). Of course, it should not be used (unless for some reason you really target the IE rendering engine only), but I thought it would be interesting to mention it.

**Edit:**

- IE still [supports it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535225%28VS.85%29.aspx).
- Firefox [has dropped support in 3.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/col).
- Safari does not seem to support it, but the [documentation indicates otherwise](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/HTMLTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001262-col).

Overall, I don't understand the reasoning behing abandoning this tag. It would appear to be very useful (at least for manual HTML publishing).

Comment: Is anybody actually reading my answer? I did not say it should be used in real life for real website. It was a historical remark, and I suggested using this only if targeting IE rendering engine (not necessarily for webpages).

Comment: Firefox didn't drop support in 3.5; it never had support for this.

Comment: I am reading this 12 years after :-) are you still alive? I find your historical note very important as nowadays standards lack support of table columns semantics, forcing web designers to bastardize design, so I added more notes about the past (and hopefully the future) in my answer.

Comment: Jan Turoň: [Probably not](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15716/jan-zich): *"Last seen more than 7 years ago"*. That usually means an abandoned or lost account.

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML5 messed up the col attribute functionality...

It is really uncool that HTML5 deprecated most of the `col` attributes and did not add the support for the `style` and `class` attributes. Modern browsers still [holds support for its `width` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col), but not for others. The width support will probably hold as it is used in [table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) render algorithm.

#### ...which can be fixed by defining CSS class series...

To achieve similar functionality without the need of editing every row, it can be achieved by defining

```
.right-1 td:nth-child(1),
.right-2 td:nth-child(2),
.right-3 td:nth-child(3),
.right-4 td:nth-child(4),
.right-5 td:nth-child(5), ...
  { text-align: right; }
```

which can be a single line with help of some CSS preprocessor / generator, but still acceptable without it as most web tables has reasonable number of columns. Then to right-align the third column, you can just

```
<table class="right-3">
...
</table>
```

#### ...but it is just a poor hack :-(

CSS classes should hold the semantics. If they imply particular styles (like in the example above), it is semantically just legalized inline `style` attribute, merging the HTML with the design (CSS should separate it). This is what Bootstrap styles do, and this is what you should avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6), which may be an issue, but it'll work in [Internet Explorer 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7) (or later), Firefox, [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29), etc. It'll align the third column right and all of the subsequent columns left.

```css
td + td + td { text-align: right; }
td + td + td + td { text-align: left; }
```

Comment: it won't work at all if I do <td rowspan='2'> in the first cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two "kinds" of column styles - use one as [TD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) and one as [TH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th). Then, declare a class for the table and a sub-class for that table's THs and TDs. Then your HTML can be super efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The current draft of [CSS Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#table-pseudos) specifies structural selectors for grids. If implemented, we will be able to do things like:

```
th.price,
th.price || td {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Of course, that doesn't help us today -- the other answers here offer enough practical advice for that.

Comment: Was it implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this [excellent description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66448223/906385), here's a complete solution for 12 columns, and includes both `<th>` and `<td>`:

```css
/* table column text alignment */
.col-r-1 td:nth-child(1),
.col-r-1 th:nth-child(1),
.col-r-2 td:nth-child(2),
.col-r-2 th:nth-child(2),
.col-r-3 td:nth-child(3),
.col-r-3 th:nth-child(3),
.col-r-4 td:nth-child(4),
.col-r-4 th:nth-child(4),
.col-r-5 td:nth-child(5),
.col-r-5 th:nth-child(5),
.col-r-6 td:nth-child(6),
.col-r-6 th:nth-child(6),
.col-r-7 td:nth-child(7),
.col-r-7 th:nth-child(7),
.col-r-8 td:nth-child(8),
.col-r-8 th:nth-child(8),
.col-r-9 td:nth-child(9),
.col-r-9 th:nth-child(9),
.col-r-10 td:nth-child(10),
.col-r-10 th:nth-child(10),
.col-r-11 td:nth-child(11),
.col-r-11 th:nth-child(11),
.col-r-12 td:nth-child(12),
.col-r-12 th:nth-child(12) {
  text-align: right;
}

.col-l-1 td:nth-child(1),
.col-l-1 th:nth-child(1),
.col-l-2 td:nth-child(2),
.col-l-2 th:nth-child(2),
.col-l-3 td:nth-child(3),
.col-l-3 th:nth-child(3),
.col-l-4 td:nth-child(4),
.col-l-4 th:nth-child(4),
.col-l-5 td:nth-child(5),
.col-l-5 th:nth-child(5),
.col-l-6 td:nth-child(6),
.col-l-6 th:nth-child(6),
.col-l-7 td:nth-child(7),
.col-l-7 th:nth-child(7),
.col-l-8 td:nth-child(8),
.col-l-8 th:nth-child(8),
.col-l-9 td:nth-child(9),
.col-l-9 th:nth-child(9),
.col-l-10 td:nth-child(10),
.col-l-10 th:nth-child(10),
.col-l-11 td:nth-child(11),
.col-l-11 th:nth-child(11),
.col-l-12 td:nth-child(12),
.col-l-12 th:nth-child(12) {
  text-align: left;
}
```

To use (this would right-align the 2nd and 3rd columns):

```html
<table className="table text-left col-r-2 col-r-3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Widget</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Sprocket</th>
            <th>100</th>
            <th>$4.57</th>
            <th>Works well</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Rocket fuel</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>$114.57</th>
            <th>Spicy</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/text/#text-alignment), you can globally align the table with `text-right` or `text-left`, and then tweak which columns don't match the whole table; I'd imagine other CSS frameworks would have something similar.

Answer (score -1):

You really want:

```
<col align="right"/>
```

But it looks like [Gecko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(software)) doesn't support this yet: it's been [an open bug for over a decade](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=915).

(Geez, why can't Firefox have decent standards support like [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6)?)

Comment: Align is a deprecated attribute so Firefox has no reason to support it.

Comment: Hmm yes, but what was the reason for its deprecation? It seems to be useful. If not the align attribute, it would be useful to style it using CSS. I know that it could possibly lead to some precedence issues (because nowhere else an element can transfer styles to other element), but still ...

Comment: There are only 4 properties allowed on columns, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119106/why-is-styling-table-columns-not-allowed

Comment: Those 4 are the only *CSS* properties.  HTML4.01 allows more document attributes on the col tag.  For example, "span" (which would be a little silly to put in CSS).  And "align" is deprecated in 'table' and 'caption', but I don't see anywhere that says it's deprecated for 'col'.

Comment: "Geez, why can't Firefox have decent standards support like IE6?)"
HAHA! fantastic comment! So untrue but indeed funny!

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery to apply *class* to all 'tr's unobtrusively:

```javascript
$(”table td”).addClass(”right-align-class″);
```

Use enhanced filters on *td* in case you want to select a particular *td*.

See [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

Comment: He just wants the third column aligned.

Comment: Plus, it's an overkill and may cause FOUC.

Comment: Does that actually work with the four non-ASCII double quotes (three of one type and one of another type)? The syntax highlighter doesn't like it (though it *is* weird). Where was it copied from?

Answer (score -2):

The `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags that lives inside tables are designed for this purpose. If you have three columns in your table and want to align the third, add this after your opening `<table>` tag:

```
 <colgroup>
     <col />
     <col />
     <col class="your-right-align-class" />
 </colgroup>
```

along with the requisite CSS:

```css
.your-right-align-class { text-align: right; }
```

From the [W3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium):

> #### Definition and Usage
>
> - The `<col>` tag defines attribute values for one or more columns in a table.
> - The `<col>` tag is useful for applying styles to entire columns, instead of repeating the styles for each cell, for each row.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work for HTML email in GMail.

Comment: Email clients have limited support for many kinds of styling, including and especially non-inline styles—e.g., styling based on classes. To work in all email clients, the individual TDs may need `style="text-align: right;"` or `align="right"`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238115/using-text-align-center-in-colgroup for better explanation.

Comment: Agreed... this solution doesn't work even when not associated with email clients.  Did you actually test it before you posted it?

Comment: `colgroup` would be ideal, but in HTML5 it got less useful.