# Right aligning one column and left aligning the other, within one table

Tags: html, css, html-table, text-alignment

I have created an HTML table with two columns.  I want the first column containing text to be right aligned, but I want the second column to stay left aligned as it contains check boxes.  For presentation it would look, but I’ve no idea.  I have tried creating a td class="column1" and then *text-align: right;* in the CSS, but no luck.

How can I do it?

**HTML**

```
<td class="column1">Retrieve Logs:</td>
<td class="column2"><input type=checkbox name="getcamlogs" checked="checked"></td>
```

**CSS**

```css
td.column1 {
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the code you posted, works fine in my browser.

Comment: really? Still wont work on mines :/

Comment: Okay works, a simple space was stopping it! Typical! Thanks very much!

Comment: This answer to a  similar question is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984864/3421814

Comment: The canonical may or may not be *[Better way to right align text in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332406/better-way-to-right-align-text-in-html-table)*. E.g., [an answer addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332406/better-way-to-right-align-text-in-an-html-table/1332421#1332421) the redundancy and compression before going on the wire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go; this should work :)

```
<style>
    #mytable {width:500px; margin:0 auto;}
    #mytable td {width:250px;}
    #mytable .left {text-align:right; background:#333;}
    #mytable .right {text-align:left; background:#666;}
</style>

<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td class="left">1</td>
        <td class="right">2</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: As a stylistic point I would try to avoid having classes called left and right when you are using them to change alignment from left and right. Its just a recipe for confusion. :)

Comment: Well yes, but this is just for demonstration purposes :)

Comment: If your table has many rows and you want to save bandwidth, I'm wondering if there's a Javascript trick to do this. Instead of adding a class to every cell in the table.  Anyway, just a thought.

Comment: Before considering the bandwidth, the actual size ***after compression*** (this is more or less automatic), both in absolute and relative terms, should be measured. With a lot of redundancy, the compression has the potential to be very efficient.

Comment: Why `text-align:right;` for `.left`? (And `{text-align:left;` for `.right`?)