# How to apply text-align left in the first column and text-align right in the others

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a Table to style. How can I apply `text-align:left;` just for the first column and `text-align:right;` for the other columns?

Here my table example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gianlucaguarini/hAv7P/

At the moment the text-align is left for all the columns.

Comment: Could you please minimize the markup to only the relevant parts and also share your code here on SO?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to specify the following CSS:

```
.table td,
.table th
{
    text-align:left;
}

#right,
.table td + td,
.table th + th
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

[An example is at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mWeYM/).

You can read more about adjacent siblings CSS selector at *[5.7 Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)*.

Answer (score 32):

You might want to look at the `:first-child` pseudo-class ([W3C definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child)) - this is exactly the kind of thing it was designed for.  You could use it like this:

```
.table td {
    text-align: right;
}

.table td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}​
```

The `:first-child` pseudo-class means the selector only matches the first `<td>` in each `<tr>`.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xv5Cn/1/

Comment: Just to note - you can also use `:nth-child(n)`, so for the second child you would do `.table td:nth-child(2){}`, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle. Just follow this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/hAv7P/9/

All you need to do is add a class to the  which you want aligned and then add CSS as in the fiddle.

```html
<h1>First Accordion</h1>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">

      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Fondo/Sociedad</th>
            <th>Actual</th>
            <th>Rent. A.</th>
            <th>Patr. Actual</th>
            <th>Tae A.</th>
            <th>Reg. CNMV</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Iurisfond, F1</td>
            <td>111,88</td>
            <td>0.13 %</td>
            <td>3.404.808,19 euro</td>
            <td>1.53%</td>
            <td class="rightalign">3015</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>CAT OCC BOLSA ESPANOLA</td>
            <td>14,84</td>
            <td>1,55 %</td>
            <td>2.043.608,62 euro</td>
            <td>10,43 %</td>
            <td class="rightalign">3766</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>INVESRIONS AGO, SICAV</td>
            <td>20,19</td>

            <td>3,75 %</td>
            <td>26.817.819,33 euro</td>
            <td>20,57 %</td>
            <td class="rightalign">3015</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DIXION INVESTMENT, SICAV**</td>
            <td>10,30</td>
            <td>0,006 %</td>
            <td>4.731.059,54 euro</td>
            <td>0,71 %</td>
            <td class="rightalign">2274</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>GAMAVO, SICAV**</td>
            <td>7,20</td>
            <td>3,99 %</td>
            <td>20.469.027,45</td>
            <td>56,52 %</td>
            <td class="rightalign">11</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>CAT OCC ESPANOLA</td>
            <td>1,12</td>
            <td>1,45 %</td>
            <td>4.297.723,66</td>
            <td>2,15 %</td>
            <td class="rightalign">321</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto; ">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Fondo/Sociedad</th>
              <th>Actual</th>
              <th>Rent. A.</th>
              <th>Patr. Actual</th>
              <th>Tae A.</th>
              <th>Reg. CNMV</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Iurisfond, F1</td>
              <td>111,88</td>
              <td>0.13 %</td>
              <td>3.404.808,19 euro</td>
              <td>1.53%</td>
              <td>3015</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>CAT OCC BOLSA ESPANOLA</td>
              <td>14,84</td>
              <td>1,55 %</td>
              <td>2.043.608,62 euro</td>
              <td>10,43 %</td>
              <td>3766</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>INVESRIONS AGO, SICAV</td>
              <td>20,19</td>

              <td>3,75 %</td>
              <td>26.817.819,33 euro</td>
              <td>20,57 %</td>
              <td>3015</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>DIXION INVESTMENT, SICAV**</td>
              <td>10,30</td>
              <td>0,006 %</td>
              <td>4.731.059,54 euro</td>
              <td>0,71 %</td>
              <td>2274</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>GAMAVO, SICAV**</td>
              <td>7,20</td>
              <td>3,99 %</td>
              <td>20.469.027,45</td>
              <td>56,52 %</td>
              <td>11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>CAT OCC ESPANOLA</td>
              <td>1,12</td>
              <td>1,45 %</td>
              <td>4.297.723,66</td>
              <td>2,15 %</td>
              <td>321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne"> <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have messed up a bit, i cant align properly the info in the Tab. Once the tab is collapsed i would like to view the info perfectly aligned as in the top tab jsfiddle.net/mWeYM/2