# text alignment in table field

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to align the value data to right in the array push table. I couldn't do it. Thank you in advance.

```
foreach ($reps as $rep) {
    array_push($reptList,
        array(
            'id' => $rep->id,
            'value' => 'Rs. '.number_format($rep->value, 2),

        )
    );
}
```

Comment: what is error in this

Comment: it displaying without alignment from left. I want to align "number_format($rep->value, 2)'s data to right. want to code html inside json

Comment: Please post your desired output. What do you mean by alignment?? array has only key and value that's it.

Comment: I want to put <right > html alignment code to number_format($rep->value, 2).  like  'value' => 'Rs. '.<right > number_format($rep->value, 2)</right >

Answer (score 0):

add span tag to your number value in array

```
foreach ($reps as $rep) {
                array_push($reptList,
                    array(
                        'id' => $rep->id,
                        'value' => 'Rs. <span style="text-align:right">'.number_format($rep->value, 2).'</span>',

                    )
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via PHP.

In your view file html table, apply css for right text align.

Please refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1332648/4198099) given by ***[Matt Howell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2321/matt-howell)***.

Comment: oh the link is not match with my table

Comment: You need to apply css on your table td. That's it.