# html table with column in monospace font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to create an html table using css. The first column is to be in monospace font, as it contains computer code.

The font-family attribute does not seem to work, however. This is the html file:

```
<html>    
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>    
<body>    
<table cellspacing="0" class="software">
<COLGROUP class="command">
<COLGROUP>
<tr>
  <td>command 1</td>
  <td>description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>command 2</td>
  <td>description</td>
</tr>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

The corresponding css file contains the following:

```
table.software{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13pt;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}    
table.software td{
    text-align: left;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 5px;
}    
.command{
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 300;
}
```

I would be most grateful for a pointer of how to achieve the change of fonts. Thanks!

Greetings,
Michael

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238115/using-text-align-center-in-colgroup and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119106/why-is-styling-table-columns-not-allowed should explain why this is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COL` and `COLGROUP` support a limited number of CSS styles.

You can use the **[`nth-child(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)** CSS3 selector instead, where `x` is the number of the column (1 for the first column) you want to style:

```css
table.software{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13pt;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}    

table.software td {
    text-align: left;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 5px;
}    

table.software td:nth-child(1) {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 300;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="software">
<tr>
  <td>command 1</td>
  <td>description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>command 2</td>
  <td>description</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by giving the class name to the corresponding `td`. Just like the following.

```
<body>    
<table cellspacing="0" class="software">

<tr>
  <td class="command">command 1</td>
  <td>description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="command">command 2</td>
  <td>description</td>
</tr>
</table>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in the class you declared. the command class should be in the respective td tags
Here is the html code:

```
<html>    
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
</head>    
<body>    
<table  class="software">
<tr id="d">
  <td class="command">command 1</td>
  <td>description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="command">command 2</td>
  <td>description</td>
</tr>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```